# move_uploaded_file() in php returns true but file not found inside the directory

Tags: php

Please i need help on this.

I was uploading an image to my server using the move_uploaded_file() method, the method returns true  bu the uploaded file was not found inside the specified directory on my server. i have checked thoroughly, searched for the file on the server in case it was uploaded to another directory, checked the permission on the directory but all seems perfect. i really dont know what went wrong .
Here is the snippet of the code.

```
$uploaddir = './upload_dir/';
$allowed = array('gif', 'png', 'jpg','bmp');
$filename = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = array();
if (!in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
    $data['status'] = 'error';
    $data['error_message'] = 'Invalid file type';
}
else{
    $file_name = time() . '_' . uniqid() . '_' . basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);
    $file_name = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\.\-]+/i', '_', $file_name);
    $file = $uploaddir . $file_name;

    if (isset($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $file)) {
        $data['status'] = 'success';
        $data['file_name'] = $file_name;
    } else {
        $data['status'] = 'error';
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you given permissions to the folder

Comment: are you trying to update the information in DB also???

Comment: check if you have a upload_dir folder in the same location where this file is.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'])` instead of `isset($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'])` for security reason check [here](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.is-uploaded-file.php)

And for the upload dir use `$uploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/upload_dir/";` instead of `$uploaddir = './upload_dir/';` to get absolute path instead of relative one.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone. I gave the wrong permission to the folder. that seems to be the problem for my own case.